# The activity loses focus when home key button is pressed on Android

Tags: android

When I press the home button on my phone, and when I return to the application, it loses the focus completely, it loses track of  where activity was; i.e. the Activity returns to principal state. How to avoid that so that when I press the home key and return to the app; to return to the where the activity was?

I need the solution to work for all devices?

Thanks.

Comment: Save the state in `onStop()` and load the state in `onStart()`.

Comment: @Vucko some example?

Comment: How can I give you an example when you did not post any code? I trully do not know what you need to save in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Well when you press the **home** button, the [activity's lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) methods will be called (first `onPause()`, then `onStop()`), and then when you return, if in the meantime your operating system didn't call `onDestroy()` (this happens when you force close an app or are running out of memory), your Activity will call `onResume()` method. If it was destroyed, it will call `onCreate` and start from the beginning.

So basically what you need to do is **override** (`CTRL+O` in Android studio to open the override menu) these methods to save your application state, save the important parameters of your app (since you've not shared any code, I cannot presume what these are) and to then later restore the state your app had previously come to.